# Magento ECE deployment duration

Tags: magento2, magento2-cloud

I was wondering how long a deployment of Magento ECE was supposed to take. Everytime I push on Magento Cloud it takes 30 minutes at least. I wonder if that is "Magento normal" or not?

Apparently Magento ECE has a normal deployment duration: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRu7D_aIF9c

Is there any way to increase this process speed ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to decrease the time of deployment:

1. Move SCD on build phase [Build phase](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/live/sens-data-over.html)
2. Enable SCD on demand [SCD_ON_DEMAND](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/env/variables-intro.html#scd_on_demand)
3. Use SCD matrix [SCD_MATRIX](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/env/variables-deploy.html#scd_matrix)

Comment: And what if we have changes in the static content ? Does that mean that we have to run it manually ? It seems that a lot of changes affect static content, so it will make it even more complicated/slow